# Text overlaps placeholder if VoiceOver is turned on on iPhone

Tags: javascript, placeholder, voiceover

I have an input with dynamically loaded value. When value appears on input field, placeholder should disappear. Everything works fine but when I turn on VoiceOver placeholder does not disappear and text overlaps it.

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/t8ykvp8e/

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder text" value="">

setTimeout( function() {
  $('input').attr('value', '123')
}, 2000)
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery's [`val` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the input element's value. Using `attr` only modifies the element's value attribute (in other words, its initial value), which might account for the strange behavior in combination with VoiceOver.

```
$('input').val('123');
```

Also see: [Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Comment: Thanks, but I've just try this solution and it doesn't help me